# In regards to memory, is there a difference between reading output into an array and reading output into a while loop?

Tags: bash

If the output of `command` is small enough there doesn't seem to be a difference, where memory is concerned, between the following two constructs.

```
readarray -t arr < <(command)

for a in "${arr[@]}"; do
  ...
done
```

and

```
while read a; do
  ...
done < <(command)
```

what happens when the output of `command` is very large?

In the first case it's obvious that the whole output is stuffed in the array variable `arr` ... not very efficient or welcome for very large output.

Does the `while; do ...; done < <(command)` pass through one line at a time? does bash buffer some subset of the command's output? or does bash stuff the whole thing into memory?

Edit: Fix title.

Comment: For the worst-case memory use scenario you envision (within the domain and responsibility of bash as opposed to kernel-level FIFO behavior), `while read` would need to have a different implementation than just calling `read` over and over. It's just a specific case of `while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done` -- `read` in a `while` loop means the exact same thing it means anywhere else, where it only reads up to the character given with `-d`, or a newline if that argument isn't passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version with process substitution connects the shell and the command with an anonymous pipe. Just like any normal `|` pipe, this means the command's output is processed as it is generated with just a small amount of buffering (64KB on modern Linux kernels). It also means the command will block if the loop doesn't read fast enough.

Comment: It's probably also worth pointing out that `read` operates a byte at a time, so nothing is read from the output side of the FIFO until it's wanted.

Comment: So, if the buffer is filled before the next read, the data is lost?

Comment: No, if the buffer fills up the writer blocks until the reader drains the buffer.